# Laravel 9 Event Queue: Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, int given, called in Grammar.php

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-9, laravel-events

I'm working with Laravel 9 and for registration of my website, I tried adding this event as the register form action:

```
$data = $request->validated();

event(new RegisterNewUserEvent($data));
```

And here is the `RegisterNEwUserEvent`:

```
class RegisterNewUserEvent implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public mixed $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}
```

And this event has assigned with these two listeners:

```
        RegisterNewUserEvent::class => [
            MakeNewUserRecord::class,
            MakeNewMemberRecord::class
        ],
```

**`MakeNewUserRecord:`**

```
class MakeNewUserRecord implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function handle(RegisterNewUserEvent $event)
    {
        $firstName = $event->data['fname'];
        $lastName = $event->data['lname'];
        $userName = $event->data['uname'];
        $mobilePhone = $event->data['phone'];
        $hashPassword = Hash::make($event->data['password']);
        $randomString = Str::random(20);

        $user = User::create([
            'usr_first_name' => $firstName,
            'usr_last_name' => $lastName,
            'usr_user_name' => $userName,
            'usr_mobile_phone' => $mobilePhone,
            'usr_password_hash' => $hashPassword,
            'usr_str' => $randomString,
        ]);

        $event->data = $user->id;
    }
}
```

**`MakeNewMemberRecord:`**

```
class MakeNewMemberRecord implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function handle(RegisterNewUserEvent $event)
    {
        $member = Member::create([
            'mbr_usr_id' => $event->data,
            'mbr_type_id' => 7,
        ]);
    }
}
```

These event listeners work fine but as soon as I tried implementing `ShouldQueue` to the event class and the listeners classes, I get this error when register new user:

### **Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, int given, called in C:\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 1021**

[image]

And I follow the error stack, I can see that this error is returned when the event is called:

[image]

I don't know really what's going wrong here! So if you know, please let me know...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since both listeners are Queueable, its data will be serialized and stored somewhere (for example: in the database, the place depends on queue connection), so you can't modify or change the event data after it has been dispatched which means `$event->data` will always be an array in every listener

my suggestion: remove `MakeNewMemberRecord` from current event, create a new event (`RegisterNewMemberEvent`) for that listener, and dispatch `RegisterNewMemberEvent` after creating the user

```
    RegisterNewUserEvent::class => [
        MakeNewUserRecord::class,
    ],
    RegisterNewMemberEvent::class => [
        MakeNewMemberRecord::class,
    ],
```

```
class MakeNewUserRecord implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function handle(RegisterNewUserEvent $event)
    {
        $firstName = $event->data['fname'];
        $lastName = $event->data['lname'];
        $userName = $event->data['uname'];
        $mobilePhone = $event->data['phone'];
        $hashPassword = Hash::make($event->data['password']);
        $randomString = Str::random(20);

        $user = User::create([
            'usr_first_name' => $firstName,
            'usr_last_name' => $lastName,
            'usr_user_name' => $userName,
            'usr_mobile_phone' => $mobilePhone,
            'usr_password_hash' => $hashPassword,
            'usr_str' => $randomString,
        ]);

        RegisterNewMemberEvent::dispatch($user->id);
    }
}
```

```
class RegisterNewMemberEvent implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public int $userId;

    public function __construct($userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }
}
```

```
class MakeNewMemberRecord implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function handle(RegisterNewMemberEvent $event)
    {
        $member = Member::create([
            'mbr_usr_id' => $event->userId,
            'mbr_type_id' => 7,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Note: i guess `return false` inside `handle` method won't stop the propagation of an event since you are using queue so the above implementation will make it possible to stop other listeners to be run